# Exec Shield patch

Tags: linux-kernel

The Exec Shield patch was removed from the Debian repositories a few months ago. Where can I download the patch ?

I found this link but files are from 2006: [Ingo Molnar link](http://people.redhat.com/mingo/exec-shield/)

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that recent kernels no longer necessitate this; It looks like it has been supercded (by PaX/NX bit?)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit#Linux

> The support for this feature in the 64-bit mode on x86-64 CPUs was added in 2004 by Andi Kleen, and later the same year, Ingo Molnar added support for it in 32-bit mode on 64-bit CPUs. These features have been in the stable Linux kernel since release 2.6.8 in August 2004.